# What are polar coordinates of the origin and why is $\arg(0) =$ undefined, an option?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have come here from reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32803/552998) and but it didn't really answered my question.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) says the cartesian co-ordinates are converted using $$x=r \cos \theta$$ $$y = r \sin \theta$$
where $r≥0$ but that doesn't make sense because those conversions are found using the definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ which are $$\sin \theta = \frac{y}{r},$$ $$\cos \theta =\frac{x}{r}$$ where $r>0$ and thus $r≠0$.

So for $(0,0)$ those conversions are not valid.

Also from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739462) answer, we may let $\theta = \arg (0,0)$ be undefined or $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is why is "$\arg (0) =$ undefined" even an option when all real numbers are perfect candidates for it? Why is the "convention" of leaving it undefined even a thing? What are we afraid of? Multiple values? Because surely, $\arg(z)$ has multiple values even when $z≠0$. So why "undefined" for $z=0$?

Comment: We are not afraid of multiple values, but maybe we are afraid of discontinuous functions. The point is that it is impossible to define $\operatorname{arg}$ in such a way that it is continous in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: One rarely if ever sees $\sin \theta$ defined as $\frac yr.$ If one does, the symbols $y$ and $r$ in the definition have nothing to do with the polar coordinates you're trying to convert.

Comment: We aren't "afraid" of "undefined".  We embrace it when it useful.  And we reject it when it is not.  And it is not useful in this case.  ANd $\arg z$ is multivalue in $\mathbb R$ but it is not multiple value in $\mathbb R/2\pi \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @DavidK No I'm saying it the other way around. It's not $y$ and $r$ have anything to do with polar coordinates, those are used independently in the definition of sines and cosines without a reference to polar coordinates. I'm saying the conversion formulas for polar coordinates come from there, unless I'm wrong and $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y =r \sin \theta$ come from somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't say, "we are afraid of 'undefined'", I'm asking **why** is leaving it undefined even considered? is it because we are "afraid" of "multiple values"? Because that doesn't make sense... for the reasons I have mentioned in the body of my question.

Comment: I can't see see how you can in one sentence say "So for (0,0) those conversions are not valid" and in the next say you can't see why it is undefined.  It is undefined *BECAUSE* the conversion are not valid.  Why in heck would *anyone* want to define something that is inconsistent, meaningless, and gives no value to anything.

Comment: @fleablood My friend, just because one "way" works for case-1 and not for case-2 doesn't mean there are not other ways to tackle case-2 or that case-2 can't happen. Those conversions work for $(x,y)$ when $x ≠0≠y$. But that doesn't mean we can't deal with the case $x=y=0$, seperately and that is the entire point of this question. For $r$, we can always go with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} =0$ but why leave undefined when $\theta$ can be any real number. After having all those values of "$\theta$" available, why go for "undefined"? I'm asking "Why".

Comment: Because any possible value we assign to $\arg 0$ will *always* in *every* possible instance will lead to inconsistencies.   Most people think that is a bad thing.  But if you want to define $\arg 0 = \sqrt \pi$ knock yourself out.  But why.  Why would *defining* something that has no purpose (and something were every value is possible is about as purposeless and useless as anything can be) ever *be* an option?  What are you trying to gain when there is nothing that can ever be gained?

Comment: @fleablood That is the point of my question. When I ask "why" not? You say because there would be inconsistencies, yes that is what I'm trying to learn by asking this question, what inconsistencies? What problems do I run into?

Comment: @fleablood One reason I don't want it to be undefined is because otherwise you can't write down the polar form for complex number $(0,0)$ as it would leave $e^{i\theta}$ undefined as well.

Comment: But defining it would mean that if $\arg w \ne \arg v$ then $\arg (0\cdot w)=\arg 0 + \arg w \ne \arg 0 + \arg v = \arg (0\cdot v)$ so $0\cdot w \ne 0\cdot v$.   But more importantly $\arg 0$ the angle of a single point with itself doesn't *MEAN* anything.

Comment: @fleablood That's a good example. What do you suggest is correct— The polar coordinates of $(0,0)$ is (a) undefined or (b) $(r, \text{undefined})$. Choosing (a) would mean not every point in a plane can be located.

Comment: @fleablood As for you other part "angle of a single point with itself doesn't mean anything". Well we always have those exceptions like "degenerate" triangles even when it's just a line segment. Secondly, James Stewart in Early transcendantals, allows the polar coordinate of origin to be $(0, \theta)$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions here which are only slightly related to each other.

TL;DR: The polar coordinates of the origin are $(0,\theta)$ for any real $\theta.$

TL;DR: Setting "$\arg(0) = \text{undefined}$" is an "option" because we write definitions to suit our needs. But the "option" is just that, an option and not a necessity.

### Polar coordinates

Polar coordinates are a sometimes-useful way of mapping pairs of real numbers to points on a Euclidean plane. In order to be able to make full use of polar coordinates, for example to plot the function $r = 2 \cos\theta,$ we want every pair of real numbers $(r,\theta)$ to map to a point.

We can get that point conceptually by rotating the point with Cartesian coordinates $(r,0)$ through an angle $\theta$ around the origin.
To give a formula for the Cartesian coordinates of that point, we use the functions $\sin$ and $\cos$. The function $\sin$ can be defined in many ways; some frequently-cited definitions are:

1. The ratio  of the opposite side to the hypotenuse in a right triangle.
2. The $y$ coordinate reached by traveling a certain distance around the unit circle.
3. The solution of the ODE $f''(t) = -f(t)$ with conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1.$
4. $\sin t = t + \dfrac{t^3}{3!} + \dfrac{t^5}{5!} + \dfrac{t^7}{7!} + \cdots + \dfrac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} + \cdots.$

Only the first definition comes from the ratio of two numbers, and it needs to be supplemented with a lot of seemingly arbitrary extra rules to work for angles outside the interval $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right).$ So we might prefer the second definition to use for polar coordinates, since we can use it in all four quadrants without any further fuss.

In any case, $\sin$ is simply a function from real numbers to real numbers. You can put any real number in as its input parameter, and out comes a value. Similarly with $\cos.$

In any event, we find that after rotating the point with Cartesian coordinates $(r,0)$ through an angle $\theta$ around the origin, its image has Cartesian coordinates $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta).$

This is perfectly well-defined even if $r = 0,$ because we didn't tell the $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions what $r$ is, only what $\theta$ is.
Even if you somehow found a book that used the symbol $r$ in its definition of $\sin,$ the $r$ in that definition is meaningful only within that definition and is a completely different variable from the $r$ in the polar coordinates $(r,\theta).$ Borrowing a bit of the language of computer programming, the variables we see in the definitions of functions are only "local" variables, not "global."

So when choosing polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ for a point, let $r = 0$ and pick any real $\theta$ you want; the $\cos$ function is defined on all real numbers, so $\cos\theta$ is defined and is a real number and therefore $r\cos\theta = 0\cos\theta = 0.$ Similarly $\sin\theta$ also is a real number and $r\sin\theta = 0\sin\theta = 0.$ It's that simple. The Cartesian coordinates of this point are $(0,0).$

Conversely, if you're looking for "the" polar coordinates of the origin, any polar coordinates of the form $(0,\theta)$ for real $\theta$ are possible.

### Defining or not defining $\arg(0)$

The complex argument function $\arg$ is used in complex analysis. It can be defined as a single-valued or multi-valued function; see [the Wolfram MathWorld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html) for details.

There is some relationship between the complex argument and the angle in polar coordinates, but they are not the same concept. For example, while the polar coordinates $\left(-\sqrt2,\frac\pi4\right)$ name a point with Cartesian coordinates $(-1,-1),$ we are not going to accept $\frac\pi4$ as the argument of $-1 - i,$ or even as one of the many values of the argument of $-1 - i.$

We might or might not define $\arg(0).$ I refer you to the comments by Daniel Fischer under the question you cited, [what is the argument of 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739462/139123), one of which is:

> Yes, either undefined, or any real number is an argument of $0$. Whichever choice is more convenient.

What is "convenient," then? It might be convenient to define $\arg(0)$ because we have a particular use for it.

On the other hand, it might not be convenient. We might have defined $\arg$ as a single-valued function with a finite range such as $(-\pi,\pi].$ To add $0$ to the domain, we'd have to pick a single value for $\arg(0).$ If we defined $\arg$ as a multi-valued function, on the other hand, the values of $\arg(z)$ for any non-zero $z$ are the equivalence class of a single value in $(-\pi,\pi]$ modulo $2\pi.$ Defining $\arg(0)$ as real numbers breaks that pattern.

Consider the identity on complex numbers,
$$ \arg(wz) = \arg(w) + \arg(z). \tag1 $$
As described in [the MathWorld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html), if $\arg$ is single-valued, this identity is only true modulo $2\pi.$ But if we define $\arg(0),$ then
$\arg(0) = \arg(0\cdot i) = \arg(0) + \arg(i),$ which implies that $\arg(i) = 0$ modulo $2\pi,$ which is false.

On the other hand, if $\arg$ is multi-valued, we might want to manipulate $(1)$ algebraically to obtain
$$ \arg(z) = \arg(wz) - \arg(w). \tag2 $$
Then if $w = 0$ we get $\arg(z) = \arg(0) - \arg(0).$
I think it would be challenging to find an interpretation for this in which both $\arg(1) = \arg(0) - \arg(0)$ and $\arg(i) = \arg(0) - \arg(0)$ were correct equations.

Not defining $\arg(0)$ means that we can write something like $(2)$ as an identity by using the convention that identities apply only when all their terms are defined, without having to explicitly list the exceptions.
That might be considered "convenient."

So nobody decides how to define $\arg$ because they are "afraid of" something. They define $\arg$ in a way that suits their purposes. Not defining $\arg(0)$ is only a "convention" insofar as there are a lot of mathematical works in which that decision suited the authors. It's not a universal convention, because sometimes it suits someone to define $\arg(0).$

Answer (score 0):

The origin has polar coordinates $ (r,\theta)$ defined as
$$ ( 0, t )$$
for *any* polar angle $t$.

Let me say with some caution... in rectangular coordinates since the origin is
$$ (0,0)$$
we tend to continue the habit or custom and assume it as some sort of convention.

In cases where our curve is going through the origin it presents a minor difficulty. For example the circle with polar equation $r= \sin (\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4} )$ can still  be thought of as having polar coordinates $(0,0)$ at the origin. However we like to take the point representation as

$$(0,  \dfrac{\pi}{4} )$$

rather than $(0,0) $ in order *to avoid discontinuity* in the polar angle at $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, derivatives takes taken would be smooth continuous.